# String gets cut while passing it as an argument of a function in bash

Tags: bash, function, shell

I defined a function as follows:

```
function determineIpaOrProject
{
 echo "In function ${1} "  # SAY POINT FUNCTION 
}
```

Now I passed a argument in its function call as follows :

```
determineIpaOrProject "/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa"
```

Expected Output :

```
"/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa"
```

Obtained Output :

```
/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\
```

I cannot understand the problem to give this ambiguous result I even tried with quotes it didn't work .

ACTUAL CODE :

```
function determineIpaOrProject
{
 echo "In function ${1} "  # SAY POINT FUNCTION
}

input=$1

determineIpaOrProject $input
```

execute :

```
sh test6.sh /Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa
```

This doesn't work :)

While if I pass $1 only it works

Comment: Works for me. I'm getting `In function /Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa`.

Comment: also works for me. what version of bash are you using?

Comment: @RobertMuil determineIpaOrProject "/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa" it works true My bad I didn't notice as I thought it was obvious from the error I got I have updated the question please have a look sorry :)

Comment: @choroba True My bad I am sorry Ive updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must quote the $1 to read "$1", and the $input to read "$input":

```
function determineIpaOrProject
{
 echo "In function ${1} "  # SAY POINT FUNCTION
}

input="$1"

determineIpaOrProject "$input"
```

Comment: The quotes on `input="$1"` are not strictly necessary, the others are (and exist in the original code).

Comment: True, that. It's only the $input that strictly needs quoting.

Answer (score 3):

2 mistakes here:

1. Don't escape the spaces inside double quotes
2. Use `printf "%q"` to print desired output

Use this script:

```
function determineIpaOrProject { printf "%q\n" "${1}"; }

determineIpaOrProject "/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/Kindle 4.9.1.ipa"
```

**Output:**

```
/Users/prabhukonchada/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/Kindle\ 4.9.1.ipa
```

Comment: actually this would be user input through another script on top of this so the user sends the input in that format only with spaces escaped inside double quotes so please suggest an alternative

Comment: How is user entering this string?